# Understanding functional operator: Lambda

Tags: java, string, arraylist, lambda

I have an an arraylist called Semesters of Semester objects

```
private ArrayList<Semester> Semesters
```

I wrote the following code to printout a string using the objects(Semester) in the list(Semesters)

```
String report = year + "\n";
for (Semester s : Semesters) {
    report += s.toString() + "\n";
}
```

Then I got a tip on netbeans where the entire above code can be written in one line like this:

```
String report = year + "\n";
report = Semesters.stream().map((s) -> s.toString() + "\n").reduce(report, String::concat);
```

I am an intermediate java student and I am trying to understand this feature which I find to be very useful but can't quite get my head around it.

Please help me understand how these two pieces of code are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Java lambdas, but going by the `map` and `reduce\fold` operations from the functional programming paradigm, this is how the 2 snippets are equivalent:

1. `map` basically applies the particular function to each element in the collection. In this case, that function/method is `s.toString() + "\n"`. This is the same as iterating over the collection and applying the function to each element via a foreach loop.
2. `reduce` is a fold operation i.e. it concatenates each element returned by the map operation to the original string `report`.

So in your original code

```
String report = year + "\n";
for (Semester s : Semesters) {
    report += s.toString() + "\n";
}
```

You basically operate on the element `s`, and then concatenate the result of that operation to `report`. Using a lambda, you first operate on the whole collection in the `map` phase, and then traverse the collection returned during mapping and concatenate each element to `report` in the `reduce` phase.

Answer (score 0):

- `semesters.stream()` will give a `Stream<Semester>` object for one time usage (stateful like iterator).
- `.map(...)` is given a function interface: an interface with only one method with parameter type Semester.
- The lambda exoression will generate an instance of a generated interface containing a method with Semester parameter and String as result type.
- Hence map yields a Stream
- Map will later iterate over the Semester-s, apply the method and collect the String.
- `Stream<String>.reduce(String startValue, stepFunction)` will let the operation (iterating) start collecting a single String, initializing to startValue, on every step: `result = result.concat(return value of map method).

I hope I have got the explanation right.

```
System.out.println("Mapping Semester to String...");
Stream<String> sems = Semesters.stream().map((s) -> {
        System.out.println("map call " + s);
        return s + "\n";
    });
System.out.println("Reducing String stream to String...");
String report = sems.reduce(year + "\n", String::concat);
```

The above shows eager/lazy evaluation. Maybe look into the Builder Pattern, for what happens under the hood. Try out `parallel` and `filter`.

```
String report = year + "\n"
    + semesters.stream()
        .filter(...)
        .sorted(...)
        .map(Semester::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the equivalent functionality broken down using anonymous classes:

```
Function<Semester, String> toStrFn = new Function<Semester, String>() {
  @Override
  public String apply(Semester semester) {
    return semester + "\n";
  }
};

BinaryOperator<String> reducer = new BinaryOperator<String>() {
  @Override
  public String apply(String lastResult, String currentValue) {
    return lastResult.concat(currentValue);
  }
};

String report = year + "\n";
Stream<Semester> semesterStream = Semesters.stream();
Stream<String> stringStream = semesterStream.map(toStrFn);
report = stringStream.reduce(report, reducer);
```